# javah multiple classpath

Tags: android, java-native-interface, classpath

I think I'm doing the classpath wrong on the command line, and I get the following error:
My android program uses Bitmap from the package android.graphics.Bitmap

```
thomas@THOMASDESKLINUX:~$ javah -verbose -classpath :/home/thomas/Documents/LinuxProgramming/AndroidSDKs/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-8.jar;/home/thomas/Documents/LinuxProgramming/EclipseWorkspace/RenderScene/bin org.me.renderscene.Billboard
Error: No classes were specified on the command line.  Try -help.
bash: /home/thomas/Documents/LinuxProgramming/EclipseWorkspace/RenderScene/bin: is a directory
```

and javah cant find the class

thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem with your command is that you are using the Windows Path Separator `;` on the command line, rather than the Linux Path Separator `:`. I also recommend to add the current directory to javah: `.`, the correct command to generate header in your case is:

```
javah .:/home/thomas/Documents/LinuxProgramming/AndroidSDKs/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-8.jar:/home/thomas/Documents/LinuxProgramming/EclipseWorkspace/RenderScene/bin org.me.renderscene.Billboard
```

**Tip**: javah doesn't need all dependency libraries to generate the headers, it will output warnings but thats OK. So using this tip, we can generate the headers with:

```
javah .:/home/thomas/Documents/LinuxProgramming/EclipseWorkspace/RenderScene/bin org.me.renderscene.Billboard
```